# Cannot bind ng-change when I use this directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

ng-blur, ng-focus events are working

However, **ng-change** is not working for **contenteditable div**.

I have changed the div to be editable and this must react like a `textarea`.

so I used contenteditable div. Can any one please help me find a working solution?

```
directive('contenteditable', function () {
      return {
          restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
          require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
          link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
              if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

              // Specify how UI should be updated
              ngModel.$render = function () {
                  element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
              };

              // Listen for change events to enable binding
              element.on('blur keyup change', function () {
                  scope.$apply(readViewText);
              });

              // No need to initialize, AngularJS will initialize the text based on ng-model attribute

              // Write data to the model
              function readViewText() {
                  var html = element.html();
                  // When we clear the content editable the browser leaves a <br> behind
                  // If strip-br attribute is provided then we strip this out
                  if (attrs.stripBr && html == '<br>') {
                      html = '';
                  }
                  ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
              }
          }
      };
  })
```

Comment: What do you mean "**ng-change** is not working for **contenteditable div**"? It works fine in this [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ovr9uLur/).

Answer (score 0):

ng-change only works with `input`, `<select>`, `<textarea>` elements it can be used with `div`.

refer this link [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-change.asp)

**Syntax**

```
<element ng-change="expression"></element>
```

Supported by `<input>`, `<select>`, and  `<textarea>`.